# How can I convert a BouncyCastle X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, .net, itext, bouncycastle

Is there any way to convert a `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate` to `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2`?

The inverse operation is easy, combining `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser` with 
 `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Export()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy!!

```
using B = Org.BouncyCastle.X509; //Bouncy certificates
using W = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

W.X509Certificate2 certificate = new W.X509Certificate2(pdfCertificate.GetEncoded());
```

And now I can validate certificate chain in the server:

```
W.X509Chain ch = new W.X509Chain();
ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = W.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
if (!ch.Build(certificate))
   res |= ErroresValidacion.CAInvalida;
```

Useful to validate pdf certifcates extracted with iTextSharp.

Comment: This won't work on certain platforms - you need to use `new W.X509Certificate2(pdfCertificate.GetEncoded());`

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/ApiCompat :

> Most users of X509Certificate and X509Certificate2 objects assume that
>   the object is immutable except for the Reset()/Dispose() methods, the
>   use of Import violates this assumption.

In other words, trying to use import throws an exception in .net core. You should now use:

```
new X509Certificate(cert.GetEncoded());
```

but, according to the .net API analyzer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer),

> warning PC001: X509Certificate2.X509Certificate2(byte[]) isn't supported on macOS

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
var x509Certificate = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(bouncyCert);
var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(x509Certificate);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

I guess that is the best answer:

```
var cert = pdf.Certificates[0];//Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate
        var cert50 = new X509Certificate();
        cert50.Import(cert.GetEncoded());
```

Comment: This is weird... the OP asked for a way to convert *"to an X509Certificate2"* but you convert to a *"X509Certificate"*. And correcting that, all that remains is something already said in the accepted answer by kaptux.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as it converts to a `X509Certificate`, not an `X509Certificate2` object. It also adds no *new* logic compared to the accepted answer.