# How to convert BouncyCastle X509Certificate to .NET Standard X509Certificate2 while retaining the private key?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, .net-standard

I need to convert a generated BouncyCastle `X509Certificate` to `X509Certificate2` with the private key getting loaded in the resulting **.NET Standard** `X509Certificate2` object. Is that possible?

There is an answer for a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150799/5048935 , but after generating a BouncyCastle certificate and converting it to .NET `X509Certificate2` the resulting object has its `HasPrivateKey` property set to "false".

## Context

I need to load a certificate and a private key (separate Base64 strings without headers and footers) to a `X509Certificate2` object to pass it on to the app from a .NET Standard 1.6 library. The problem is, **there is no `PrivateKey` property in the `X509Certificate2` class in .NET Standard**! So the only way for me to actually load the private key in a `X509Certificate2` object is to combine it with the certificate itself in a .pfx file and load it like that in a constructor.

I've got suggestions to use BouncyCastle for that ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/44465965/5048935 ), so I first generate a BouncyCastle `X509Certificate` from the Base64 strings and then try to convert it to `X509Certificate2` while retaining the private key.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you've got so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way I've found is to go through an in-memory PFX stream. Assuming you've already loaded your Bouncy Castle cert in `bcCert`. Note: If you are going to be saving the .NET `X509Certificate2` anywhere, the "alias" is what it's going to be called in the UI later, otherwise it's irrelevant (other than it needs to be the same for both calls).

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

var pkcs12Store = new Pkcs12Store();
var certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(bcCert);
pkcs12Store.SetCertificateEntry(alias, certEntry);
pkcs12Store.SetKeyEntry(alias, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(certKey.Private), new[] { certEntry });    
X509Certificate2 keyedCert;
using (MemoryStream pfxStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    pkcs12Store.Save(pfxStream, null, new SecureRandom());
    pfxStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    keyedCert = new X509Certificate2(pfxStream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: @Kevin I am currently using the same code to convert in .net compatible Certificate and it is working perfectly. But now I have to move to bc-fips-1.0.2.dll and in this new dll I am not able to found PKCS12Store Class in it. Is there any alternative or new way to achieve this? I am struggling from days to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ashu, I'm unable to reply directly to your comment, but for newer versions of bouncy castle, you can change Kevin's answer to:

```
var pkcs12StoreBuilder = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder();
var pkcs12Store = pkcs12StoreBuilder.Build();
```